# if i lose the private key generated with a csr, does that mean i need to have a new certificate issued?

Tags: ssl, plesk

i was in the process of installing a new ssl certificate via plesk and deleted it, i forgot to save the private key that was generated with the csr that was used to issue the certificate. does that mean i now have to generate a new csr, and have the certificate provider re-issue a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'd need to start over. Certificate Authorities usually offer a second (backup) try for free (for cases like yours).